# Disable filtering options in SelectItem on client

Tags: java, gwt, smartgwt

[image]
Sorry for the Czech language on the picture, but it's not important.

On the picture you can see SelectItem after clicking its drop down button. On the first row on this drop down you can see extra filtering input, which I need to get rid of.

I think this only happens when you load values into SelectItem using DataSource (setOptionDataSource method) but anyway, I would expect setting some flag would disable this but after lots of trying (and crying about how much time this is taking since I expected it is gonna take one minute). So please, if anyone knows how to disable this, let me know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must have something like `selectItem.setPickListProperties(props);`

Just do `props.setShowFilterEditor(false);`